# Show a branch name with a commit message when merging in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge, git-branch, git-commit

Is there any way to switch that on in a repo settings or somehow else? If no, is there any workaround?

[image]

Above, you can see a PR that has a lot of commits from different branches, merged into `stage` before, but we can't exact recognize from which ones. What I expect is showing a branch names in opposite to each commit message, but I don't know if it possible in Bitbucket. I'm talking about UI at Bitbucket website, if not obviously.

Answer (score 0):

> What I expect is showing a branch names in opposite to each commit message

Why do you expect that? When you merge branch `other` into branch `stage`, the only branch you are "on" at that point is `stage`. There's nothing else to know.

Well, there is *something* else to know: the branch `other` may be a *parent* of the merge commit, if there is a merge commit. But the name `other` is in no sense "attached" to the merge commit itself, and there is nothing about the commit message that would say what the name of the other parent branch was at the time, unless you specifically created the merge commit with a commit message that *does* say that.

Also, don't forget that branch names are volatile; good practice often entails deleting the branch name after it is merged, so there would be no name to show you in any case.

It sounds, rather, as if the goal here is that you want to see a graph of the history. Bitbucket isn't necessarily going to show you that, but your local Git will, by using some graphing tool. You can use `git log --graph` of course, but you can alternatively use `gitk` or any other Git GUI that draws these sorts of graph.

Even then, however, you won't see any useful history unless these are *true merge commits*. If you do your "merge" by a Squash or Rebase "strategy", which is possible on Bitbucket, then these commits have *no* historical relationship with any other branch than this one (`stage`).

Comment: I do expect that because it is possible for BB, because it store all the commit history and can fetch any info whatever need. BB just can do that under the hood for enhancing UX for us.

Comment: Bitbucket is just a web site. It isn't Git. What Bitbucket shows, it shows; what it doesn't, it doesn't. As I said, Git will show you the history nicely, esp. using supplementary UI tools. No need to sit around hoping some web site will do the work for you.

Comment: I got, but we're definitely need BB to do that. If it can't, well, when we have to automate that ourselves. And what I'm asking is *does it provide that somehow or not*